# How to call native (C or assembly) code from a .NET (C#) program (under Linux)?

Tags: .net, linux, assembly, .net-core, x86-64

The error of dotnet run defined [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/blob/master/src/corehost/cli/fxr/fx_muxer.cpp). I'm trying to run assembly code via C library `DllImport` in C# with .Net core x64 Linux. How to do this correctly?

C#:

```
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
class Program{
[DllImport("lib.so")] public static extern int foo ();
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int code = foo();
System.Console.WriteLine(code);
}
}
```

C `my.c`:

```
    #define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
EXPORT int foo(void);
int foo(void)
{
    extern int _start();
    return _start();
}
```

Assembly `asm.s`:

```
.text
   .globl _start

   _start:               
   mov $1, %rax
   ret
```

The program goal is to return zero result code from assembly via C library. The following error message is printed; no exception is raised:

```
Hosting components are already initialized.
Re-initialization to execute an app is not allowed.
```

I have compiled C and Assembly sources using GCC:

```
gcc -shared -fpic -o lib.so my.c asm.s
```

Comment: The gcc command line is wrong: `-nostartfiles` makes no sense when compiling (`-c`) but only when linking. And `lib.so` does not contain `asm.o`.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Re-initialization to execute an app is not allowed.
> ```

I'm not sure what's happening here, I only have a **suspicion**:

> ```
> gcc -shared -o lib.so my.o
> ```

Using this command line you generate a file named `lib.so` that contains the file `my.c`. But **not** the file `asm.s`!

This means that this file does not contain the symbol `_start`.

Now the question is: What happens at the following line of code:

> ```
> return _start();
> ```

Maybe the code will jump to the `_start` symbol of the application (which is running the C# program).

This is like re-starting that application without re-setting the global variables to the initial values and without a valid stack frame...

**EDIT**

> Unable to find an entry point named 'foo' in shared library 'lib.so'. at Program.foo()

The problem is that the "`static`" keyword has a completely different meaning when used in a "method" in C++, C# or Java or when used in a "function" in C or C++:

In a function or a global variable the "`static`" keyword means that the function or variable can only be used from inside the same file.

(Very similar to "`private`" in C#.)

You have to remove the "`static`" in the C program, but you have to keep the "`static`" in the C# program.

**EDIT 2**

I'm not sure if you are aware how calling C from .NET (or assembly from C) code works:

The assembly program is just executed as if it was part of the .NET program. If you call `syscall` with `rax` set to `231` (`exit_group`), your assembly function behaves like a .NET function calling `Environment.Exit()`:

Your C# program is stopped at once. For this reason, `code=foo()` will not return any value because `foo()` will terminate your C# program.

To return a value from an assembly function, you simply write the value to be returned to the `rax` register. And you finish the function with a `ret` instruction:

```
_start:
    mov $1, %rax
    ret
```

Unfortunately, this seems NOT to be the reason for the exception, so there is another problem in your program...

Comment: I have changed build comand to _as --64 -o asm.o asm.s && gcc -c -fpic my.c -o  my.o && gcc -shared -o lib.so my.o asm.o_ and now I have an exception _Unhandled exception. System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'foo' in shared library 'lib.so'.
   at Program.foo()_

Comment: @ВладимирСмирнов: You can pass source files to gcc for it to assemble or compile in the same command it's going to link.  Like `gcc -shared -fpic -o lib.so my.c asm.s`.  But anyway, since `foo` is `static` in your `.c` file, unsurprising that it's not visible in the symbol table of the library.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: Agreed with your guess, I expect that the OP's `lib.so` will have an unresolved `_start` symbol that programs that link it need to define.  So dynamic linking resolves it to the CRT entry point `_start`.  A `call rel32` would be out of range between the executable and a shared library, but the `_start()` function call already compiles to `call _start@plt` because of using `-fpic` and C declaring it as an `extern` function, not "hidden" ELF visibility.

Comment: I have added full C# code and unmarked foo as static but now I have _Hosting components are already initialized. Re-initialization to execute an app is not allowed._ when running _gcc -shared -fpic -o lib.so my.c asm.s_.

Comment: @ВладимирСмирнов Unfortunately, I can't help you with the exception, but please read the "EDIT2" part about another problem in your program.

Comment: @MartinRosenau, I have changed assembly code to your EDIT2 and still have the same message _Hosting components are already initialized. Re-initialization to execute an app is not allowed._